# Display loading gif before the page appears

Tags: vbscript, page-lifecycle

First of all I'm a complete beginner when it comes to VBscripts.
I have only one asp file written in VB that starts a batch file.
The thing is that I want something that indicates that the page is loading like a gif. The batch takes almost 10 minutes to run and what I get is a blank page until it is finnished.

This is my entire code

```
<%@ Language = VBScript %>
<HTML>
   <script runat="server" language=VBScript>
        ' The batch file is running here
        Dim myExecutor  
        Dim commandline

        commandline = "cmd.exe /c C:\test.bat "
        Set myExecutor = Server.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        myExecutor.Run commandline,0,true
        Set myExecutor = Nothing
        Response.Write "The batch run is finnished <p> "
   </script>
   <body>
       The batch is loading. <!--renders after batch is finnished :/ -->
   </body>
</HTML>
```

I tried to run an onclick event `<asp:Button Text="Click here" OnClick="run_batch" runat="server"/>` but gives me a 500 page error when i use the `sender As Object, e As EventArgs` as parameters probably because I dont have the classes and only runns everything in one asp file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code will execute as soon as the page loads. Define what you want to do as a `Sub` and call that in the `onload` event handler. The event will fire once everything on the page is loaded.

I tested the following in an hta and it works. Not sure how well it converts to asp.

```
<HTML>
   <script language=VBScript>
        sub DoStuff()
            document.Write "<p>Doing stuff </p>"
            CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "ping localhost",0,true
            document.Write "<p>The batch run is finished <p> "
        end sub
   </script>

   <body onload="DoStuff()">
   </body>
</HTML>
```

Alternatively for a button approach just use

```
<button onclick="DoStuff()"> Do Stuff </button>
```

Comment: Your code works but can I run an .hta file without prompting to download or run it? Chrome just download the .hta file. I want to run it in the browser.

Comment: I don't have a webserver setup on my machine, hence why I created the .hta. You should just take the approach from this code and apply it to your original script.

Comment: I run this from visual studio with a local IIS. It seems I can only run .hta explorer and other browsers only download the file. .hta seems to be some kind of internet explorer solution.